# Can't use viewclient.py in windows env

Tags: monkeyrunner

I want to executable `monkeyrunner` in windows env, but I get the error:

```
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
File "D:\Work\technology\Myeclipse\Android_SDK\windows-x86-20130219\sdk\tools
AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 25, in <module>
if 'monkeyrunner' in sys.executable:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Did you [read the wiki](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki)? The error seems to be indicative of a windows path difference.

Comment: Are you using **AndroidViewClient >= 4**? Then use `python` instead of `monkeyrunner`